# What is the significance of 'map' in python ? How does it impact if map is not used

Tags: python

If I don't use 'map' in the below code while taking input for variable 's' & 'd' then  it shows a runtime error.I didn't get the reason behind it as I hoped that input could had been taken without 'map'.

```
t= int(input())
for x in range(t):
    n =int(input())
    
    s=list(map(int,input().split()))
    d=list(map(int,input().split()))
    
    count = 0
    for i in range(n): 
            if s[i]==d[i]:
                count += 1
    
    print(count)
```

Testcase-
Input

```
2--- #(t)

4----#(n)
1 2 3 4 ---#(s)
2 1 3 4-----#(d)
```

output -

```
2
```

#output is 2 because only 2 digits (3&4) match in line s&d in values and index position

Comment: The `map()` function in this case is being used to turn the input strings into integers.

Comment: `s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Comment: I would agree that `map` is not needed here since `"4" == "4"` just as fine as `4 == 4`. What error are you facing? `s=input().split()` (and same for d) should work just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the significance of map is that it is an iterator that returns a result without using a loop.

Without a result you get a runtime error because python doesnt know what to work with.
You can leave it out for alternatives, but those are (mostly) less efficient and require more runtime.

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) applies a function to each element of an interable (list, tuple etc). In your case it applies `int` (converts elements into integers) to each character of the list returned by `split` (e.g. `['1', '2', '3', '4']`).

But your code works just fine without converting the elements into integers. In this case it is comparing characters as follows:

```
t = int(input())
for x in range(t):
    n = int(input())

    s = list(input().split())
    d = list(input().split())

    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if s[i] == d[i]:
            count += 1

    print(count)
```

I tested it with the same input you provided.